# Upload a file to Google Drive with embedded browser c#

Tags: google-drive-api

Since I am unable to capture browser window close event using the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync API, I followed this link (http://www.daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/) to create an embedded browser and authenticate the user. I am unable to continue further to use the access token to upload a file in google drive. Is there any example available to continue from the above link to upload/download a file from Google Drive.

Regards,
Amrut

Answer (score 0):

From the same author, there is a documentation how to upload/ download files to Google Drive.

Like with most of the Google APIs you need to be authenticated in order to connect to them. To do that you must first register your application on Google Developer console.   Under APIs be sure to enable the `Google Drive API` and `Google Drive SDK`, as always don’t forget to add a product name and email address on the  consent screen form.

> Make sure your project is at least set to .net 4.0.

Add the following [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Drive.v2/) Package

```
PM> Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2
```

In  order to [download](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-download/) a file we need to know its file resorce the only way to get the file id is from the `Files.List()` command we used earlier.

```
public static Boolean downloadFile(DriveService _service, File _fileResource, string _saveTo)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_fileResource.DownloadUrl))
            {
                try
                {
                    var x = _service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(_fileResource.DownloadUrl );
                    byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_saveTo, arrBytes);
                    return true;                  
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Using `_service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync` we can pass it the download url of the file we would like to download. Once the file is download its a simple matter of wright the file to the disk.

Remember from creating a directory in order to [upload](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/) a file you have to be able to tell Google what its `mime-type` is.  I have a little method here that try’s to figure that out.   Just send it the file name.   Note: When uploading a file to Google Drive if the name of the file is the same name as a file that is already there.   Google Drive just uploads it anyway,  the file that was there is not updated you just end up with two files with the same name.     It only checks based on the `fileId` not based upon the file name.    If you want to Update a file you need to use the Update command we will check that later.

```
public static File uploadFile(DriveService _service, string _uploadFile, string _parent) {

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(_uploadFile))
            {
                File body = new File();
                body.Title = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(_uploadFile);
                body.Description = "File uploaded by Diamto Drive Sample";
                body.MimeType = GetMimeType(_uploadFile);
                body.Parents = new List() { new ParentReference() { Id = _parent } };

                // File's content.
                byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(_uploadFile);
                System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
                try
                {
                    FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = _service.Files.Insert(body, stream, GetMimeType(_uploadFile));
                    request.Upload();
                    return request.ResponseBody;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else {
                Console.WriteLine("File does not exist: " + _uploadFile);
                return null;
            }           

        }
```

Comment: I have gone through this tutorial but the problem here is in this tutorial DriveService object created by calling AuthorizeAsync API is used to upload/download a file. But I only have access token with me (http://www.daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/). How can I continue further to upload/download with only access token is my question?